# How to provide the entity package to the HIbernate 5 with Map approach?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am new to hibernate and trying to learn it with Hibernate 5 and Spring Boot Application.

I am using the Map approach to set the data-source related properties as shown below:

```
if(null == standardServiceRegistry) {

                //the following map is an alternative to the hibernate.cfg.xml file
                Map<String, String> dbSettings = new HashMap<>();
                dbSettings.put(Environment.URL, "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/saurabh");
                dbSettings.put(Environment.USER, "postgres");
                dbSettings.put(Environment.PASS, "root");
                dbSettings.put(Environment.DRIVER, "org.postgresql.Driver");
                dbSettings.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL, "true");
                dbSettings.put(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "create");
                dbSettings.put(Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect");
                dbSettings.put(Environment.NON_CONTEXTUAL_LOB_CREATION, "true");

                // the rest of the code is same as with the xml file
                standardServiceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(dbSettings).build();
                MetadataSources metaDataSources = new MetadataSources(standardServiceRegistry);
                Metadata metaData = metaDataSources.getMetadataBuilder().build();
                sessionFactory = metaData.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
            }
```

This works fine as far as `sessionfactory` is considered. I tried running a `Select version()` query and it works fine.

Now, I have my entities package `com.saurabh.entities` in a package parallel to the package containing above-mentioned configuration.

With this setup hibernate cannot manage to get my Entities and is not creating the tables by default.

However, if I switch to `hibernate.cfg.xml` approach, and provide following tag in xml file, it works fine.

```
 <mapping class ="com.saurabh.entities.Employee" />
```

Can someone explain what's the best way of assigning the entire entity package(s) to the Hibernate at once.

Note: I have already tried assigning `@EntityScan({basePackage="com.saurabh.entities"})` at Spring `.run()` file and `HibernateConfig` file (where I am getting session factory as shown above).

Comment: Why? Spring Boot auto configures all of that for you... So the best approach is to remove everything you have and simply start your Spring Boot application and put the configuration in `application.properties`.

Comment: Despite the fact that there is no need to do that in Sping data, I can imagine standalone app using hibenrate and having such configuration. Thats interesting!

Comment: @M. Denium I completely understand this entire thing is possible using Spring boot and spring data using Spring based configuration and application.properties. Still just say if for some reasons I have to do it the above way, how can I ?

Comment: Where do I mention Spring Data, you are reading things I didn't write. I suggest that you let Spring Boot configure Hibernate. I haven't suggest you should use Spring Data JPA. You can still use plain JPA (or hibernate if you really must) while Spring Boot configures the thing for you . If you want to configure it like that (which I really wouldn't recommend) you have to fully configure it manually and leave Spring Boot out of the mix (so no use of `@EntityScan` etc.).

Comment: As I mentioned, I am still new to this stuff. Would you please brief what should I actually be doing or better link to me an article you see fit.

Comment: As recommended by M. Deinum, I tried looking for ways to configure Hibernate with spring boot (without Spring Data) but couldn't find a way. Can someone suggest something

Answer (score -2):

MetadataSources has the right method.

```
MetadataSources metaDataSources = new MetadataSources(standardServiceRegistry);
metaDataSources.addPackage("com.saurabh.entities");
```

give it a try.

Comment: Nope. This doesn't work. As per the docs, this is supposed to add any metadata available at the package level.

Comment: Interestingly, there is another method `.addAnnotatedClass()` available in the metaDataSources which adds the class. Still it has to be added one at a time.

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari isn't that what you asked for? To add annotated clases one by one (as done in xml)

Comment: @Antoniossss What  I wanted was a way to define a package where all my entities are kept. Hibernate then can pick up all classes marked @Entity from that package. But apparently that's not possible. I will have to mention all my class name explictly using `.addAnnotatedClass(MyClass.class)`

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari nobody said it is possible in first place (in xml config). It would work ONLY if you would put all entity classes into separate JAR and point that JAR.